# No contribution in component VaR using historical method in R

Tags: r, finance, performanceanalytics, risk-analysis

I am new to R. I am using package [PerformanceAnalytics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html) to calculate Component VaR of portfolio.
 If I use **gaussian method**, it returns contribution.

```
> VaR(edhec, p=.95, method="gaussian", portfolio_method="component")
no weights passed in, assuming equal weighted portfolio
$VaR
           [,1]
[1,] 0.01193358

$contribution
 Convertible Arbitrage             CTA Global  Distressed Securities       Emerging Markets  Equity Market Neutral           Event Driven Fixed Income Arbitrage 
          0.0014400703           0.0003687009           0.0012961865           0.0032090406           0.0003479361           0.0013848605           0.0010051944 
          Global Macro      Long/Short Equity       Merger Arbitrage         Relative Value          Short Selling         Funds of Funds 
          0.0011151866           0.0015860006           0.0004412756           0.0009265836          -0.0027498306           0.0015623733 

$pct_contrib_VaR
 Convertible Arbitrage             CTA Global  Distressed Securities       Emerging Markets  Equity Market Neutral           Event Driven Fixed Income Arbitrage 
            0.12067381             0.03089608             0.10861675             0.26890849             0.02915606             0.11604738             0.08423244 
          Global Macro      Long/Short Equity       Merger Arbitrage         Relative Value          Short Selling         Funds of Funds 
            0.09344947             0.13290235             0.03697764             0.07764507            -0.23042800             0.13092245 

>
```

But If I use **historical method** it just returns a single portfolio level value

```
> VaR(edhec, p=.95, method="historical", portfolio_method="component")
no weights passed in, assuming equal weighted portfolio
[1] 0.01439231
>
```

Is this correct? Am I missing something?

**EDIT**
I want to calculate component VaR of each part using historical simulation method.

Comment: Does `help(VaR)` give any insight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'historical' method is not a 'simulation' method.  It is a measure of the realized historical loss quantile.

I have added historical contribution to `PerformanceAnaltytics` in v 1.4.3574 on R-Forge.

Your example now produces:

```
> VaR(edhec, p=.95, method="historical", portfolio_method="component")
no weights passed in, assuming equal weighted portfolio
$hVaR
  hVaR 95% 
0.01419502 

$contribution
Convertible.Arbitrage             CTA.Global  Distressed.Securities       Emerging.Markets  Equity.Market.Neutral           Event.Driven Fixed.Income.Arbitrage           Global.Macro      Long.Short.Equity 
        -0.0006396664          -0.0001887839          -0.0007621405          -0.0020091076          -0.0001331756          -0.0008771216          -0.0004113300          -0.0006202640          -0.0010782781 
  Merger.Arbitrage         Relative.Value          Short.Selling         Funds.of.Funds 
     -0.0002735736          -0.0005046562           0.0012263158          -0.0008257281 

$pct_contrib_hVaR
 Convertible.Arbitrage             CTA.Global  Distressed.Securities       Emerging.Markets  Equity.Market.Neutral           Event.Driven Fixed.Income.Arbitrage           Global.Macro      Long.Short.Equity 
        0.09012547             0.02659862             0.10738139             0.28307218             0.01876371             0.12358159             0.05795412             0.08739178             0.15192344 
  Merger.Arbitrage         Relative.Value          Short.Selling         Funds.of.Funds 
        0.03854501             0.07110328            -0.17278113             0.11634054
```

It is available from SVN now, should be available in binary form 'soon', and will be included in the next release of `PerformanceAnalytics`

Comment: Most helpful solution anyone could get on SO. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving off the `portfolio_method="component"` part returns all of the individual percent contributions.

```
> VaR(edhec, p=.95, method="historical")
```

Results:

```
    Convertible Arbitrage CTA Global Distressed Securities Emerging Markets
VaR              -0.01916    -0.0354             -0.018875        -0.044605
    Equity Market Neutral Event Driven Fixed Income Arbitrage Global Macro
VaR             -0.006385     -0.02254               -0.00929     -0.01624
    Long/Short Equity Merger Arbitrage Relative Value Short Selling Funds of Funds
VaR          -0.02544        -0.013455      -0.013175      -0.07848      -0.021265
```

Though why that is, I'm not sure, as I'm not familiar with the package or VaR in general.

`help(VaR)` does seem explicit to the behaviour. Not to my untrained eyes anyway.

Comment: Component VaR is not normal VaR. So can not leave this parameter.