# Convert data from CSV file time series

Tags: r, csv, time-series

I have data like this in my csv file

```
Date          AAPL      MSFT       GOOG
8/19/2014   100.53  45.78787879     522.7956989
8/18/2014   99.16   45.56565657     517.0967742
8/15/2014   97.98   45.24242424     511.7204301
8/14/2014   97.5    44.71717172     508.1362007
8/13/2014   97.24   44.52525253     506.5232975
8/12/2014   95.97   43.95959596     499.9641577
8/11/2014   95.99   43.63636364     498.8888889
8/8/2014    94.74   43.63636364     494.4086022
8/7/2014    94.48   43.66666667     493.5842294
8/6/2014    94.96   43.17171717     493.5483871
```

I am reading it like this

```
price_data <- read.csv("C:\\Prices.csv")
```

I want to convert it time series. I have seen question at [R - Transform Data frame to Time Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835587/r-transform-data-frame-to-time-series) and [Convert data frame with date column to timeseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732461/convert-data-frame-with-date-column-to-timeseries). 
But, in my case I have more than one column to be converted. No of columns can be varying.
One solution seems to be separate each column and convert to time series and then merge back using cbind.

What is best way to do it.

**EDIT**

I want to calculate component VaR, using this data. I also have positions of symbol as

```
MSFT 1000
AAPL 1520
GOOG 398
```

VaR in package "PerformanceAnalytics" accepts time series. Is there any other way I can pass this data to function?

Comment: By merge back you want to get a data.frame with 3 columns (Date, Value and the Ticker) as output?

Comment: I mean I want it like Date(for time series), AAPL, MSFT, GOOG. So it will be like 4 columns. To be more specific I want to calculate component VaR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243094/no-contribution-in-component-var-using-historical-method-in-r

Comment: You actually just want to convert the `Date` column into a timeseries, correct? 'Cause it wouldn't make sense to convert ALL columns.

Comment: In this case it's better to use a list with the 3 time series if you need xts format. Edit: you do not describe clearly what you want, an example of output would be helpfull.

Comment: Yes and to calculate VaR using package PerformanceAnalytics, this method only accepts time series data I guess

Comment: Have you tried `price_data$Date <- ts(price_data$Date)`?

Comment: It seems that I need to correct the date format. Do I?

Comment: You could go through `as.zoo`, doing `as.ts(as.zoo(df))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Lines <- "Date          AAPL      MSFT       GOOG
8/19/2014   100.53  45.78787879     522.7956989
8/18/2014   99.16   45.56565657     517.0967742
8/15/2014   97.98   45.24242424     511.7204301
8/14/2014   97.5    44.71717172     508.1362007
8/13/2014   97.24   44.52525253     506.5232975
8/12/2014   95.97   43.95959596     499.9641577
8/11/2014   95.99   43.63636364     498.8888889
8/8/2014    94.74   43.63636364     494.4086022
8/7/2014    94.48   43.66666667     493.5842294
8/6/2014    94.96   43.17171717     493.5483871"

library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

rets <- diff(z, arithmetic = FALSE) - 1
VaR(rets)
```

giving:

```
            AAPL         MSFT         GOOG
VaR -0.005010481 -0.001461903 -0.001090975
```

Comment: It seems to be working when I run commands from R console UI. While if I try it to save it in .r file and running it from Rscript.exe it shows "Error in `[.xts`(R, , column): subscript out of bounds".

Comment: thanks i got it working. it was separator issue. and your answer do what is required.